# Can you skip the credits in Pokémon X and Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

On Pokémon X, I tend to Battle the Elite 4 a lot to get lots of money and exp points for my Pokemon. However, every time that I beat them all, although I leave with more money and exp points, I have to wait through the credits.

I know that you can hold down the A or B buttons to speed the credits up, but I would like to know if there's a way to skip them entirely?

Comment: Honestly, if you want to grind faster, get Grand Duke/Duchess at the Battle Chateau. Under the right conditions, you get to face level 65 Audinos, and the Gym leaders, Elite 4, and even the Champion with higher level mons. This works very well for both money and experience.

Answer (score 14):

Just reset the game.The game saves when it puts you in the hall of fame. I forget if it tells you exactly when it saves, but if developers names are scrolling along the screen it's safe to reset.

Per [Ivo Beckers' comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157224/can-you-skip-the-credits/157226?noredirect=1#comment328238_157226) it might not be safe to do this the first time since it's a bit different--but if you're just farming the elite four after winning once you can reset freely.

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work the very first time because you then have to battle AZ.

Answer (score -3):

You can't skip it, but you can 'fast-forward' it by holding down the A or B button.

Comment: He mentioned that in the question